# Python: How to stop a loop after 20 times and print the results on a user inputted list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
numlist = [] 
maxnumlist = 20
while len(numlist) < maxnumlist:
    item = input("Enter a number: ")
numlist.append(item)
print numlist
print "Here are some stats"
print (numlist)
lowestnum = min(numlist)
highestnum = max(numlist)
total = sum(numlist)
ave = float(sum(numlist)) / len(numlist)
print (lowestnum)
print (highestnum)
print (total)
print (ave)
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

I need the program to run this way:
User enters any number, 20 separate times (hence the question is looped 20 times)
Python takes all the recently inputted numbers, and calculates the sum, minimum, maximum, and average.
Python then prints/displays those calculations

For some reason, no matter what I try, I can't get it to run correctly. I spent literally 6 days on this, and am so lost. I would just like to get this over with so I can try to learn from it and finally move on. I bet it's a super simple fix, but it's beyond me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong `numlist.append(item)` is outside the while loop so list is never growing and while is running for infinite times

```
numlist = [] 
maxnumlist = 20
while len(numlist) < maxnumlist:
    item = input("Enter a number: ")
    # notice this statement is inside while loop
    numlist.append(item)
print numlist
print "Here are some stats"
print (numlist)
lowestnum = min(numlist)
highestnum = max(numlist)
total = sum(numlist)
ave = float(sum(numlist)) / len(numlist)
print (lowestnum)
print (highestnum)
print (total)
print (ave)
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iXksi21h

THIS WORKED! Jeez, I feel like a complete idiot. All it took was an indent...

Comment: glad it helped you

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without your error message, but I believe that all you need to do is indent the `numlist.append(item)` line.  As the code reads now, the user inputs 20 numbers but `numlist` only `append`s the last one since `numlist.append(item)` is outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: I still can't believe how simple this was... Ugh. Thank you!

Does anyone know why my question is -3? Did I ask it the wrong way?

Comment: I don't know why people were down voting it, but in the future it would be much easier to help if you included an error message or incorrect output in your original post. For example, in your code wouldn't give an error, but you could have said that when you print `numlist` you only got the most recent `item`.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, you have one line indented wrong

```
numlist = [] 
maxnumlist = 20
while len(numlist) < maxnumlist:
    item = input("Enter a number: ")
    numlist.append(item)

print numlist
print "Here are some stats"
print (numlist)
lowestnum = min(numlist)
highestnum = max(numlist)
total = sum(numlist)
ave = float(sum(numlist)) / len(numlist)
print (lowestnum)
print (highestnum)
print (total)
print (ave)
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

results:

```
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: 8
Enter a number: 9
Enter a number: 10
Enter a number: 11
Enter a number: 12
Enter a number: 13
Enter a number: 14
Enter a number: 15
Enter a number: 16
Enter a number: 17
Enter a number: 18
Enter a number: 19
Enter a number: 20
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
Here are some stats
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
1
20
210
10.5
```

Comment: That's the strange part, I wanted the stats to also display right before the numbers on the same line, but I got it to work this way only http://pastebin.com/iXksi21h